# Adding other DOM elements to a view in Backbone

Tags: dom, view, backbone.js

I'm in a situation where I'm manipulating sub elements of a view and not sure if I'm properly handling them.  This specific example is I have a carousel that has left and right buttons that disappear on certain events (for example, if you get to the end of the carousel in one direction).  In order to manipulate these objects I've been doing something like this, but it doesn't feel right:

```
$(this.el).find('.right-paddle').hide();
```

Or in some cases during instantiation call something like this:

```
this.rightPaddle = $(this.el).find('.right-paddle');
```

so that I can do something like this later:

```
this.rightPaddle.hide();
```

Is this bad form?

Comment: OT: it is a good practice to use `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512090/whats-the-difference-between-this-el-html-and-this-el-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to manipulate these objects I've been doing something like
>   this, but it doesn't feel right:

Why not? What's wrong about it? Is it too much to write? Views are bound to 'parent' DOM elements and more often than not they have some children or elements within it that must be *found* in order to manipulate them. It's perfectly valid

> Or in some cases during instantiation call something like this:
>   If you refer it quite often it's a good habit to cache the instance since DOM traversal is expensive. In your case it seems to be perfectly valid.
>
> Is this bad form?

No. There is more than one way to do it. Do what makes your application more maintainable and readable and not necessarily strive for premature optimizations or hard-to-read code, unless it's very performance critical (should still be easy to read though :)

Does this help alleviate your concern?

Comment: Yeah. It seems all right to me. When I'm dealing with elements in a view, I tend to do this: `this.$('.right-paddle').hide()` which is a shortcut for `$(this.el).find('.right-paddle').hide();` Also, I think it's fine to point to the element as a variable if you're going to be accessing that variable a lot or for convenience sake. Like @PhD said, this is a "whatever works for you" scenario.

Comment: Cool, concerns completely alleviated :)