# What is the difference between $el and el in Backbone.js views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

Can you please tell the difference between `$el` and `el` in Backbone.js views?

Comment: Have you checked it in the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)

Comment: I did not get what does this statement mean "cached jQuery object" for $sl

Comment: It's just a reference to the jquery object and saves you looking it up each time it's used which can be bad for performance.

Comment: [`this.$el = $(this.el)`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-129), more or less.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between:  $(this.el).html  and  this.$el.html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512090/whats-the-difference-between-this-el-html-and-this-el-html)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
"el"  is HTMLElement
"$el" is jQuery
```

lets say that you do this

```
var myel = this.el; // here what you have is the html element, 
                    //you will be able to access(read/modify) the html 
                    //properties of this element,
```

with this

```
var my$el = this.$el; // you will have the element but 
                      //with all of the functions that jQuery provides like,
                      //hide,show  etc, its the equivalent of $('#myel').show();
                      //$('#myel').hide(); so this.$el keeps a reference to your 
                      //element so you don't need to traverse the DOM to find the
                      // element every time you use it. with the performance benefits 
                      //that this implies.
```

one is the html element and the other is the jQuery object of the element.

Comment: Is it valid to write query on this.$el ? For example write this.$el(".some-class") in order to get element with .some-class that is contained in view's html.

Comment: Not for me, `this.$el('.class')` nets me $el is not a function, i have to use find: `this.$el.find('.class')`

Comment: @JamesLock you need to use `this.$('.class')`. You're confusing a jQuery object with [jQuery's core function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). `this.$el('.class')` is like `$('.selector')('.class')`, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I think it is helpful explicitly differentiating their types rather than calling both simply elements. `$el` is `jQuery` type and `el` is `HTMLElement` type.

Answer (score 6):

[**mu is too short**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646526/what-is-difference-between-el-and-el-in-backbone-js-view#comment23956136_16646526) is exactly right:

> ```
> this.$el = $(this.el);
> ```

And it's easy to understand why, look at the [view's `_setElement` function](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L1285):

> ```
> _setElement: function(el) {
>   this.$el = el instanceof Backbone.$ ? el : Backbone.$(el);
>   this.el = this.$el[0];
> },
> ```

This ensures that the `el` property is always a DOM element, and that the `$el` property is always a jQuery object wrapping it. So the following is valid even though I used a jQuery object as the `el` option or property:

```
// Passing a jQuery object as the `el` option.
var myView = new Backbone.View({ el: $('.selector') });
// Using a jQuery object as the `el` View class property
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:  $('.selector')
});
```

## What is a cached jQuery object?

It's a jQuery object assigned to a variable for reuse purpose. It avoids the costly operation of finding the element through the DOM with something like `$(selector)` each time.

Here's an example:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(/* ...snip... */));
    // this is caching a jQuery object
    this.$myCachedObject = this.$('.selector');
},

onExampleEvent: function(e) {
    // Then it avoids $('.selector') here and on any sub-sequent "example" events.
    this.$myCachedObject.toggleClass('example');
}
```

See an [extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321584/1218980) I wrote to know more.

Answer (score 2):

In short, el gives you access to HTML DOM elements, i.e you can refer and access them, whereas $el is jQuery wrapper around el.

$el not only provides access to particular DOM element, moreover it acts as a jQuery selector and you have privilege to use jQuery library functions like show(), hide(), etc on the particular DOM element.

Comment: It is in terms of jQuery and question is about `backbone.js`

Answer (score 1):

It is so late to answer it but -->
`this.$el` is a **reference** to the element in the context of jQuery, typically for use with things like `.html()` or `.addClass()`, etc.
For example, if you had a div with id someDiv, and you set it to the **el** property of the Backbone view, the following statements are identical:

```
this.$el.html() $("#someDiv").html() $(this.el).html()
```

`this.el` is the native DOM element, untouched by jQuery.