# Backbone this.el vs this.$el

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

For the given example, what is the difference between `this.el` & `this.$el`

I understand that `this.$el` points to the jQuery object of `this.el` , which in this case is `'li'`.

When I render a view, I can choose between `this.el`, or `this.$el`. How am I able to render something to a page when I reference the jQuery object? I can see how using `this.$el.html(property)`, points to the html, but why appending `this.$el` and having it render is what confuses me.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 30,
        occupation: 'worker'
    }
});

var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var out = this.$el.html(this.model.get('name') + this.model.get('occupation'));
        console.log(this, this.el, this.$el, out);
        $('body').append(this.$el);
    },

});

var person = new Person;
var personview = new PersonView({model: person});
```

Comment: If you need jQuery methods or the cross browser support it brings, use `this.$el`, otherwise use the native DOM methods with `this.el`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between:  $(this.el).html  and  this.$el.html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512090/whats-the-difference-between-this-el-html-and-this-el-html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bojangles is correct.

`this.$el` is a reference to the element in the context of jQuery, typically for use with things like `.html()` or `.addClass()`, etc. For example, if you had a div with id `someDiv`, and you set it to the `el` property of the Backbone view, the following statements are identical:

`this.$el.html()`
`$("#someDiv").html()`
`$(this.el).html()`

`this.el` is the native DOM element, untouched by jQuery.

Comment: this.$el.html(stuff) is what was confusing me, but makes sense now - you can take the jQuery method and fill in the HTML of the original element and use it by attaching it to the DOM using this.el or this.$el.

Comment: Well... Yes. For the most part. But except in advanced Backbone techniques, the DOM element that `this.el` represents already exists on the page and should **not** need to be reattached to the DOM. The `this.$el.html(someHtmlHere)` method should update the DOM element in-place. In your example above, though, your execution is correct. The only change I would make (and hopefully you were already planning on doing this) was to `.append()` the item to a pre-existing `ul`.

Comment: Also, if you found my answer useful I would certainly appreciate you marking it as accepted :)